# Changing Key in immutable Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

What is the best way of dynamically changing the key in an immutable Map?

```
// I have a map like this:
const names = Map({
  rya: true,
  mike: false,
});

// I receive this as inputs
const inputIndex = 0;
const inputLetter = n;

// What are the operations that i need to do here to get the expected output
// [?CODE?]

// I expect this as output:
const names = Map({
  ryan: true,
  mike: false,
});
```

My solution so far seems quiet inefficient:

```
const namesEntrySeq = names.entrySeq();

const objectToModify = namesEntrySeq.get(inputIndex);

objectToModify[0] = objectToModify[0] + inputLetter;

const namesAsArray = namesEntrySeq.toArray();

namesAsArray[inputIndex] = objectToModify;

const names = Immutable.Map(namesAsArray);
```

There has to be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3):

If you're relying on the order of entities in your Map staying the same, you should be using an [`OrderedMap`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap), or doing as [Rafael said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846512/1263415) and keeping track of the order yourself.
If you use an `OrderedMap`, you can use [`#mapEntries`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/mapEntries) to updated a key in it:

```js
const names = Immutable.Map({
  rya: true,
  mike: false,
});
const letterToAdd = 'n';
const indexToUpdate = 0;

const updatedNames = names.mapEntries(([key, value], index) => {
  if (index === indexToUpdate) {
    return [key + letterToAdd, value];
  } else {
    return [key, value];
  }
});

console.log(updatedNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

Note that this is inefficient in that it will iterate through every entry in the map in order to change one. If your map is small, it probably won't matter.

---

As an aside, it doesn't seem like the way you are storing this data is conducive to the way you want to modify it. I would consider restructuring your data so that it is easier to perform the types of operations you want to on it.

Answer (score 2):

First it seems that your input is not correct to be used with Map.

Map is often a HashMap. So, that way, the keys does not have to obey any order. It seems that your input says: hey, change the key of index "inputIndex" by adding a letter at the end of the key.

If you can't change this input, you might need a List to hold the keys in some order.

```
// do not use const here. You will need to update that reference.
let keys = List(['rya', 'mike']); // keep that updated
let names = Map({
    'rya': true,
    'mike': false
});

const changeKey = function (inputIndex, inputLetter) {
    let key = keys.get(inputIndex);
    let newKey = key + inputLetter;
    names = names.withMutations(map => {
        var value = map.get(key);
        map.delete(key);
        map.set(newKey, value);
    });
    keys = keys.set(inputIndex, newKey);
};

changeKey(0, 'n');
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `mapKeys` and `OrderedMap`, as others have noted that accepting an input index assumes your map has a particular order.

```
const { Map, OrderedMap, List } = require('immutable')

const names = Map({
  rya: true,
  mike: false,
});

const orderedNames = OrderedMap(names)

const inputKey = List(orderedNames.toSeq()).get(inputIndex)

orderedNames.mapKeys((k,v) => (k === inputKey) ? k + inputLetter : k)
```

et voila

```
Map({
  ryan: true,
  mike: false,
});
```